# "Screen" effect in Java 2D graphics

Tags: java, graphics, screen, composite, alpha

This is a question that's been bugging me for some time now:

In photoshop/GIMP, there is a "screen" layer composition mode. This mode has bright colours have a strong alpha, and dark colours a weak one. Black is entirely transparent, white entirely opaque.

I would dearly love to be able to replicate this composite using Java 2D graphics, but my repeated attempts at trying to coax AlphaComposite into this have failed - and indeed I think this is outside of AlphaComposite's capabilities.

A visual example can be seen [here](http://www.zarkonnen.com/screen.jpg) .

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Any chance we can get a screenshot of what you're talking about?

Comment: Now that there is a screenshot, you may want to break it up into multiple screenshots, as certain browsers (read: Firefox) are putting part of your image underneath the tags box.

Comment: Whoops, I tried to shrink it but ended up making it disappear. Trying to fix it now...

Comment: Weird, the <img> tag was getting stripped. I had to roll it back to the original version. Anyone else want to try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like some reference code is here:

http://www.curious-creature.org/2006/09/20/new-blendings-modes-for-java2d/